# Mui function to change color to either black or with in regard to blackground color

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I was wondering which function can i use from material ui to get its characteristic property of changing text color to either white or black in regard of blackground color, if bg is dark it changes color to white and if bg is light it changes color to black.
exmaple

```
<AppBar color="primary">
     <Toolbar>
         <Typography color="inherit" > some text </Typography>
     </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

now somehow if my primary color is a dark color MUI will automatically change my text color to white, and for light color will change to black.

which function or anything basically i can use to accomplish this functionality.

i tried a css property

```
mix-blend-mode: "difference"
```

but it doesn't give black/white like in MUI, It just gives a color with contrast that makes it visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can try using Material-UI's built-in `getContrastColor` method, as in:

```
<AppBar color="primary">
     <Toolbar>
         <Typography sx={{color: theme.palette.getContrastText("YourColorHere")}}>
           some text 
         </Typography>
     </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

2. Or you can use `mix-blend-mode: "difference"` combined with `color: "white"` (and, optionally, wrap this in a parent div which has `filter: "grayscale(1)"`). See [this example](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/).